# Is there any way to use Quartz persistence with r2dbc?

Tags: java, spring-boot, quartz

I want to integrate my spring boot project with Quartz API. Everything works fine when quartz store job data in RAM Job Store, but the problem appears when I am trying to store job data in database. The reason it doesn't work is that I am using r2dbc in my project to store data in db. So is there any way to use Quartz with r2dbc (in specification it works with jdbc). Also main goal of saving data in quartz storage is to restart job if the system shuts down and check all executed jobs.